Find all real solutions to the following equations via different methods

Find all real solutions to the equation $$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac12}
+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac12}=x$$

The solution I have is somewhat a manufactured one, and I would like to know the other methods by which we can solve this question. I'll post the given solution as an answer below.

It will be more amazing to make the rhs equal to $kx$

@ClaudeLeibovici I'll try that

We will assume 
$a=\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac12}$ and $b=\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac12}$ 
$a+b=x$
And, as $x=1$ is not a solution of the original equation, we can multiply $a-b$ on both sides of the above equation
$\implies (a+b)(a-b)=x(a-b)$ 
$\implies a^2-b^2=x(a-b)$ 
$\implies x-1=x(a-b)$ 
$\implies a-b=\frac{x-1}{x}=1-\frac{1}{x}$
Now, 
$a+b+a-b=2a=x+1-\frac{1}{x}$
$\implies 2a=a^2+1$
$\implies (a-1)^2=0$
$\implies a=1$
Now undo the substitution 
$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac12}=1$
$\implies x-\frac{1}{x}=1$
$\implies x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$
But sum of two square roots cannot be negative so we discard $x=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$
Hence our answer is $$\boxed{x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=φ}$$
